# How can I replace a specific string with zero in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 30 row and 1000 column. Some column of this data have "nan" and "inf" value. I would like to replace them with zero. 
I try some code but could not get sufficient result. 
For instant i create a sample data frame like this

```
test<-data.frame(a=c("inf",1,"inf"),b=c("nan",3,"nan"))
```

and I try so many code in this regard like

```
>na_code <- c("nan", "inf")
for (i in seq_along(test)) {
+     test[[i]][test[[i]] %in% na_code] <- 0
+ }
```

I get this warrnings
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
so I try this

```
for (i in seq_along(test)) {
+     test[[i]][test[[i]] %in% na_codes] <-NaN
+ }
```

and when I want to replace NAN with zero

```html
test[is.na(test)]<-0
```

I get same warnings.
Where I do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the columns are factors you can just change the levels:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(test, function(x) {
  levels(x)[levels(x) %in% na_code] <- 0 
  x
  })
)
# a b
# 1 0 0
# 2 1 3
# 3 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different, loop-less way.  First we coerce the data to a character matrix through `as.matrix`. Then, we `sub` out the values and convert to numeric via `type.convert`.

```
type.convert(sub("inf|nan", 0, as.matrix(test)))
#      a b
# [1,] 0 0
# [2,] 1 3
# [3,] 0 0
```

You can then coerce back to data frame if necessary, but do note that with 100% numeric data it's best to use a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(test, 2, function(x){ ifelse(x %in% na_codes, 0, x) } )
```

This will return:

```
     a   b  
[1,] "0" "0"
[2,] "1" "3"
[3,] "0" "0"
```

The will all be characters. You can change back to factors later, but I assume you would rather they be numeric, in which case you just wrap an `as.numeric`

```
apply(test, 2, function(x){ as.numeric(ifelse(x %in% na_codes, 0, x)) } )

     a b
[1,] 0 0
[2,] 1 3
[3,] 0 0
```